# How to restrict images access from url?

Tags: .htaccess, file-access

I want to restrict the file access via url and also I need to allow from html view page.
My code is like this means

```
<img src="../webroot/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

The attacker simply go to inspect element and copy paste the url and get the original file from my server. Some images are user privacy so how can I prevent it.
I just also tried this htaccess method but it restrict on both from url and also in html view page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://localhost/skypeclass [R,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your .htaccess

```
<Files ~\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$>
   Order Deny,allow
   Deny from all
   allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```